# How to use the Docker remote API?

Tags: linux, docker

I installed Docker on Ubuntu 14.04, and it works fine.

Under `etc/default/docker` I have this configuration:

```
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
DOCKER_OPTS="-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

I ran `docker run hello-world` and then under `var/run/docker.sock` the file is not being written.

How I can listen from that file in order to use the [remote api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see an error message like the one shown in "[Using boot2docker to run Docker on a Mac or Windows](http://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/boot2docker.html)"

```
$ docker run hello-world
2014/08/11 15:05:55 Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.13/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

Then make sure you have set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable correctly.
With [docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/), that should be set with:

```
docker-machine env dev
```

Once that is done, then a simple GET should work:

```
echo -e "GET /images/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

This uses the [Netcat utility](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) (`nc` command).

Comment: I don't see any errors. `This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.`

Comment: Can you provide me any tips?

Comment: @OiRc What docker version are you using? Did yo try a request to test if that would stll work (as in http://blog.inovia-conseil.fr/?p=215): `echo -e “GET /info HTTP/1.0rn” | sudo nc -U /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: I'm using the 1.9 version. If i launch this -> `echo -e “GET /info HTTP/1.0rn” | sudo nc -U /var/run/docker.sock` i'll get this error `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` .

Comment: 1.21? that sounds very old. It should be 1.8 or 1.9. What `docker version` and `docker info` return?

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, my current version is 1.9.

Comment: @OiRc OK: the remoteAPI version for docker 1.9 is 1.21 indeed (http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/)

Comment: @OiRc I forgot the \\ in my previous command: `$ echo -e "GET /images/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock`: see http://blog.trifork.com/2013/12/24/docker-from-a-distance-the-remote-api/